# GUI terminals(?) reset $SHELL

Tags: shell, kde

I've been playing around with the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) for a few days and I like it.  In order to start fish in a terminal via a quicklauncher or menu, I'm using a script like this:<sup>1</sup>

```
#!/bin/sh

export SHELL=/bin/fish
exec konsole  # <- KDE's terminal emulator
```

If I run this script from the command-line, it does what's expected: starts a `konsole` whose shell is `fish`.

But run from a KDE launcher, `$SHELL` has been reset and I get `/bin/bash`.  What's more, if I replace `konsole` with `Terminal` (from XFCE), it doesn't work even from the command-line; the terminal starts up with `$SHELL` reset.  So it appears that:

- XFCE's `Terminal` will reset `$SHELL` no matter what.
- KDE's `konsole` will not reset `$SHELL` when started from the command-line.
- KDE will reset `$SHELL` when an application is started via a launcher.

If I change the default shell in `/etc/passwd`, every works.  That's fine, except there are a few users (I use more than one) I would prefer not to do this with, but I still want to quicklaunch a terminal to use fish.

Note that there are no profile, etc. files anywhere on the system that set `SHELL`.  There's just the default in `/etc/passwd`.  Also, this is not just an issue under KDE (it also happens via `fvwm`).  I've grepped through the KDE and XFCE conf directories too.

I realize this is probably just life, but I'm wondering if there isn't something I've missed here, or if anyone knows more specifically **why this would happen.**

---

<sup>1. In fact that's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) -- the reason this is irritating is I like to start a terminal with two tabs open running `mc`, meaning the work-around is more than just typing `fish`.  This is also why I can't use a `-e` type switch to the terminal command; that's what's starting `mc`, which uses a subshell based on `$SHELL`.</sup>

Comment: Why not use whatever mechanism the terminal emulator provides to run commands? Also, how are you setting `SHELL` in the launcher?

Comment: @muru I am using such a mechanism (konsole via `--tabs-from-file` and Terminal via `-e`); but what it starts is actually `mc`, which uses a subshell based on `$SHELL`.  But the SSCCE is the same.  I suppose I could use this to start a shell script so it is set the other way around.  `SHELL` by the script the launcher  laucher calls.  I have never noticed that it fiddles with the environment in any other way.

Comment: ^ Sorry, that should read "$SHELL is set by the script the launcher calls".

Answer (score 2):

For KDE look in path `$KDEDIR/share/apps/konsole` for file `shell` this post is similar to your question http://www.kde-forum.org/artikel/5064/configuring-and-customizing-konsole.html

Comment: You kinda got me with that, since I grepped through that directory `-R -i shell` but did not check filenames... However, although there's a `bash.profile` in there, I don't see anything that specifically sets the shell (and as mentioned, changing it in `/etc/passwd` works).

Comment: You could try adding /bin/fish to $KDEDIR/share/apps/konsole/bash.profile

Comment: So, what `bash.profile` turned out to be is the config file for one of my konsole profiles, named "bash" -- I added this for the user with `/bin/fish` as home shell so a konsole can be started with bash (`konsole --profile bash`) instead.  Not sure if I can do that in conjunction with the `mc` one...actually I've already found satisfactory work arounds for everything.  What I'm curious about is finding out *why* this is an issue for two separate DE entities.